# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python, machine-learning, perceptron

I have a code, which implements Perceptron manually. Unfortunately, I am receiving an error that I have no knowledge of how to fix it...
I searched and saw that this error normally occurs when a method is used and is not called, but in this point, I do not know where is any method I should be calling in the error line.

My code is here:

```
import random

class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, amostras, saidas, taxa_aprendizado = 0.1, epocas = 1000, limiar = -1):
        self.amostras = amostras
        self.saidas = saidas
        self.taxa_aprendizado = taxa_aprendizado
        self.epocas = epocas
        self.limiar = limiar
        self.n_amostras = len(amostras)
        self.n_atributos = len(amostras[0])
        self.pesos = []

    def treinar(self):
        for amostra in self.amostras:
            amostra.insert(0, -1)

        for i in range(self.n_atributos):
            self.pesos.append(random.random)

        self.pesos.insert(0, self.limiar)
        n_epocas = 0

        while True:

            erro = False

            for i in range(self.n_amostras):
                uzin = 0
                for j in range(self.n_atributos + 1):
                    uzin += (self.pesos[j])*(self.amostras[i][j])
                y = self.degrau(uzin)
                if y != saidas[i]:
                    erro_aux = self.saidas[i] - y
                    for j in range(self.n_atributos + 1):
                        uzin += self.pesos[j] + (self.taxa_aprendizado) * (erro_aux) * (self.amostras[i][j])
                    erro = True

            n_epocas +=1

            if not erro or n_epocas > self.epocas:
                break

        print(self.pesos)
    def degrau(self, u):
        if u >=0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0




entradas = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]
saidas = [0,1,1,1]

rede = Perceptron(entradas, saidas)
rede.treinar()

print(rede.amostras)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/nick/PycharmProjects/CursoMachineLearning/redes_neurais/perceptronzin.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       rede.treinar()   File "C:/Users/nick/PycharmProjects/CursoMachineLearning/redes_neurais/perceptronzin.py",
>   line 31, in treinar
>       uzin += (self.pesos[j])*(self.amostras[i][j]) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and
>   'int'

Comment: `self.pesos.append(random.random)` - you should add the result of the function: `self.pesos.append(random.random())`

Comment: And if `limiar` is a function, also do the same in `self.pesos.insert(0, self.limiar)`

Comment: What @RobinZigmond said. Plus as a side note, you're doing arithmetics on a **list**, and I believe what you want is a **numpy array** on which you can do arithmetics on the content of your arrays. But I may be wrong because I don't get all you're doing due to the language of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 19 you created a list of function **objects** instead of **floats**.
**Use:**

> `self.pesos.append(random.random())`

instead of

> `self.pesos.append(random.random)`

Comment: How is this different from what has already been suggested by others in the comments?